# Is there syntax validator for Regex?

Tags: c#

I have a textbox where user can input Regex string which shall be then used as Regex match pattern.

I wonder if there is a way to validate the syntax of the input?
How do I know if it is valid Regex pattern or not?

I would not like the user to be able to input anything, but just valid Regex pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes I think you are correct. Previous comment removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a try and catch statement to test if their input is corrupt.

```
public bool isValidRegex(string input){
     bool ret;


     ret = true;

     try{
         new Regex(input);
     }
     catch (ArgumentException){
          ret = false;
     }

     return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz.aspx) instance with the user’s input.

If the input is invalid, an `ArgumentException` will occur.

EDIT: since the other answer’s code is unnecessarily complex in my opinion, here’s my take.

```
bool IsValidRegex(string input) {
    try {
        new Regex(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, **I would *not* use this code**, since it cases the regular expression to be constructed twice: once to test for validity, and then later to actually use it. *Do not* do this. Instead, use the following:

```
Regex TryParseRegex(string input) {
    try {
        return new Regex(input);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you get a `null` return value for invalid regular expressions. As a third alternative, here’s the same method, using the .NET `TryXxx` pattern with an `out` parameter. For the record though, I find those methods badly designed. If the first .NET version had had `Nullable`s, they would probably have looked like the above method instead. So use at your own discrection.

```
bool TryParseRegex(string input, out Regex regex) {
    try {
        regex = new Regex(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautifully simple: pass off the task to the existing engine.

Comment: ?! This answer was upvoted *not even one second* after I posted it.

Comment: Would it be the same approach for a String Format? If I want to validate "000.00" is a valid syntax?

Comment: @st_stefanov I advise you to consult [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) which clearly answers this. An invalid format string will indeed raise a `FormatException`.